# Should I have entities that automatically persist?

Tags: design, clean-code, decorator

In a MVVM application (Xamarin.Forms, FWIW) I have a viewmodel that stores settings explicitly

```
public class SettingsPageViewMode : INavigatedAware
{
    ISettingsRepository settingsRepository; // injected

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters navigationParameters)
    {
        var settings = settingsRepository.LoadSettings();
        this.SomeBoolSetting = settings.SomeBoolSetting;
    }

    public bool SomeBoolSetting
    {
        get => someBoolSetting;
        set
        {
            if(someBoolSetting == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            someBoolSetting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeBoolSetting");
            UpdateSettings();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSettings()
    {
        var settings = settingsRepository.LoadSettings();
        settings.SomeBoolSetting = SomeBoolSetting;
        settingsRepository.SaveSettings(settings);
    }
}
```

I am thinking about if it's a good idea to have settings store itself automatically via a decorator that is instantiated when `ISettingsRepository` returns a `Settings` object

```
internal class AutoPersistSettingsDecorator : Settings
{
    Settings settings;
    ISettingsRepository settingsRepository;

    public AutoPersistSettingsDecorator(Settings settings, ISettingsRepository settingsRepository)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.settingsRepository = settingsRepository;
    }

    public override bool SomeBoolSetting
    {
        get => settings.SomeBoolSetting;
        set
        {
            if(settings.SomeBoolSetting == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            settings.SomeBoolSetting = value;
            settingsRepository.SaveSettings(settings);
        }
    }
}
```

This would simplify the viewmodel and make saving the settings transparent

```
public class SettingsPageViewMode : INavigatedAware
{
    ISettingsRepository settingsRepository; // injected
    Settings settings;

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters navigationParameters)
    {
        var settings = settingsRepository.LoadSettings();
        this.SomeBoolSetting = settings.SomeBoolSetting;
    }

    public bool SomeBoolSetting
    {
        get => settings.SomeBoolSetting;
        set
        {
            if(settings.SomeBoolSetting == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            settings.SomeBoolSetting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeBoolSetting");
        }
    }
}
```

Possible drawbacks:

- `Settings` looks like a data type, but comes with a behavior
- It's not really obvious that `Settings` is persisted
- Might violate the principle of least astonishment
- When the public interface of `Settings` changes, `AutoPersistSettingsDecorator` has to change, too
- Might be error prone

However, Clean Code still proposes (more or less) this design (I don't have a page number, since I'm reading on a Kindle, but it's in part 11 (Systems), in the sections about AOP, just after Figure 11-3)

> The client believes it is invoking `getAccounts()` on a `Bank` object, but it is actually talking to a set of nested *decorator* objects that extend the basic behavior of the `Bank` POJO.

Did I get something fundamentally wrong? Should I create the settings class more use-case centred? How could I possibly achieve this, since I basically have a very data-like view of a settings class. Is this approach appropriate at all when it comes to settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem behind idea of having self-persisting settings.

But I really don't like implementation. First thing, I would create `ISetting<T>` interface, with `T Value` property. Then, instead of `bool SomeBoolSetting` I would have `ISetting<bool> SomeBoolSetting` and bind to `SomeBoolSetting.Value`. This way, you can have lazy-loading of your settings, instead of having to manually load in in OnNavigated and have automatic persistence in the base class instead of calling `UpdateSetting` in every property in view model. This also simplifies the possible decorators, as you only need one type of decorator.

Quick hack what I mean. It assumes `ISettingRepository` can save and load based on key instead of having properties to be set:

```
  public interface ISetting<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     T Value { get; set; }
  }

  public interface ISettingsRepository
  {
     void SaveSetting(string name, object value);

     object LoadSettings(string name);
  }

  public class PersistedSetting<T> : ISetting<T>
  {
     private T _value;
     bool hasValue;
     private readonly ISettingsRepository _repository;
     private readonly string _key;

     public PersistedSetting(ISettingsRepository repository, string key)
     {
        _repository = repository;
        _key = key;
     }

     public T Value
     {
        get
        {
           if (!hasValue)
           { 
              // lazy loaded
              _value = (T)_repository.LoadSettings(_key);
           }

           return _value;
        }
        set
        {
           if (hasValue && _value.Equals(value))
           {
              return; // dont update if same
           }

           _value = value;
           _repository.SaveSetting(_key, _value); // persisted every time it changed
           hasValue = true;

           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }

  public class SettingsPageViewMode
  {
     ISettingsRepository settingsRepository;

     // seriously here. Use constructor injection
     public SettingsPageViewMode(ISettingsRepository settingsRepository)
     {
        this.settingsRepository = settingsRepository;

        SomeBoolSetting = new PersistedSetting<bool>(settingsRepository, "SomeBool");
     }

     public ISetting<bool> SomeBoolSetting { get; } // bind to SomeBoolSetting.Value
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Could you elaborate a bit more, how you'd implement the lazy loading of the settings in this case? Would I simply have a backing field that is assigned when the getter is accessed the first time?

Comment: @PaulK Yes. See edit.

Comment: I've just seen it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a really great solution. Is there a reason you did not use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @PaulK Didn't really think of it. Seems simpler without Lazy to me. But I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: Just two further suggestions: From my point of view, the name `hasValue` is misleading. It should be more something like `valueIsInitialized` or `valueIsLoaded`. And maybe the value *should* be loaded when setting the value. The way it is, if the value in the database is `true`, but is not loaded, and we are setting `Value` to `true`, `PropertyChanged` fires, although the property did not really change. Admittedly this is really minor.